# Data retrieval from mongodb java api

Tags: java, mongodb

I ve got a field tweets in mongodb database which contains several characteristics of the tweet stored. One of the user field which contain information about the user which post the tweet. I want to retrieve given the id of the user, some other information of the user which is stored in the database. Database's structure:

```
_id
tweet_info
user
      id
      description
      default_profile
```

I want, having the user id to retrieve field description and default_profile. What query should I perform here? My code until now:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("..", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("...");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("...");


    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("??,  ??);
    DBCursor  cursor = coll.find(query);
    System.out.println(cursor);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
             final DBObject result = cursor.next();
             Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) result.get("user");
            System.out.println(value.get("default_profile"));
            System.out.println(value.get("description"));
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

How can I retrieve this field given the user.id?? What I am trying is the following:

```
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user.id",  975789703); // id example
    DBCursor  cursor = coll.find(query);
    System.out.println(cursor);
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
             final DBObject result = cursor.next();
             Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) result.get("user");
            System.out.println(value.get("default_profile"));
            System.out.println(value.get("default_profile_image"));
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

When I am trying to perform a query like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user.name", "");
```

It returns all the users. After several minutes I am getting the message:

```
Cursor id=0, ns=iti_se.cms, query={ "user.id" : 507813128}, numIterated=0, limit=20, 
readPreference=primary
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: interrupted at shutdown
 at com.mongodb.MongoException.parse(MongoException.java:82)
 at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:314)
 at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
at twitter4j.examples.tweets.UpdateStatus.default_image(UpdateStatus.java:94)
at twitter4j.examples.tweets.UpdateStatus.main(UpdateStatus.java:112)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user.id",  userId);
```

Comment: The field id is int32. So, userID it must be inside in quotes" " or not?

Comment: Actually when I perform the query, it start runs without any effect. It just print the first cursor. It searches 10M tweets. Is it normal?

Comment: You get all tweets for current userId.

Comment: For the last twenty minutes it runs but i didnt get unitl now any result.

Comment: Do you have no result? cursor.size() == 0 ? is userId exist?

Comment: For example when I print cursor before try-catch I am getting 
Cursor id=0, ns=iti_se.cms, query={ "user.id" : 975789703}, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary 
When I am trying to print cursor.size(), nothing is happening.

Comment: if you get no results cursor.size() have to return 0.

Comment: When I am tryiung to prin cursor.size(), nothing it happen, it print nothing either in the case my query is  BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("user.name", "");

Comment: try to change: DBCursor  cursor = coll.find(query).limit(20);

Comment: The same, it is working when I am quering BasicDBObject("user.name", ""); but when I am tyring BasicDBObject("user.id", 507813128);  it return nothing. id is checked and exists in database.

Comment: I think I make sense. THe problem was due to the size of the db and lack of indexing.